# What is the difference between get all links/buttons/fields in selenium?

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, command, selenium-rc

I haven't found any documentation that answers this question, I'm just confused as to which command to use where- for example a link and a button could be the same thing? I'm sorry if this is a very basic question and I'm just being silly. Thanks in advance! 
Tara

Comment: I can only see a link being the same as a button in that a link is *styled* to look like a button. They are two different HTML elements. Please give examples.

Comment: If in selenium IDE I click on something and it comes up with "command: click" "target: link=my profile" for example, logically thats a link right? but if I put into eclipse: get all links then selenium command for click "link=my profile" it says its not found

Comment: When you say "put into Eclipse" ...what code are you using to get all the links? The `link` locator is basically for locating an `anchor` (`a`) element with a particular text property. So yeah, I'd expect it to be returned in a list of 'all links' in the page.

Comment: selenium.getAllLinks();selenium.click("link=My profile");

Comment: on separate lines.. sorry I'm new to this forum thing I'm still getting to know it!!

Comment: and when I run it it says : element not found

Comment: I would then suggest that the link is not visible to Selenium straight away. Do you need to do some action on the page to get that link to be visible & 'interact-able'? Is it in an iFrame? Can you show us the HTML of the page you are working on? Can you reproduce this on another site?

Comment: The problem is that the site that I'm doing my tests on has a lot of pop ups (not in different windows, but pop ups within the window, if that makes sense) and I can't get selenium to pick up text on those pop ups

Comment: Take the HTML of one of those popups, paste it here. It certainly sounds like it is in an IFrame.